# angularjs 1.0.8 how to replace $scope.form.$setPristne

Tags: angularjs

I don't know how I can do in angular stable version 1.0.8. The problem is in the form with validation in which I put a value and press the *Reset* button I have unnecessary message "Invalid price" (I know that form is $dirty so i should set $pristne).
In angular 1.1.1 I can call:

```
$scope.advertForm.$setPristne();
```

but how I can replace it in angular 1.0.8.

My form:

```
  <form ng-controller="AddAdvertController" name="advertForm" novalidate>
    <label>Price ($)</label>
    <input ng-model="newAdvert.price" type="number" name="price" min="100" required>
    <span ng-show="advertForm.price.$dirty && advertForm.price.$invalid">Invalid price</span>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="isUnchanged()">Reset</button>
    <button ng-click="add()" ng-disabled="advertForm.$invalid || isUnchanged()">Save</button>
  </form>
```

My controller:

```
motoAdsApp.controller('AddAdvertController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.emptyAdvert = {
      price: null
    };

    $scope.add = function() {
      alert('User added!');
      $scope.reset();
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.newAdvert = angular.copy($scope.emptyAdvert);
      if ($scope.advertForm) {
        // In angular 1.1.1 or higher
        //$scope.advertForm.$setPristne();
        // How to do in angular 1.0.8?
      }
    };

    $scope.isUnchanged = function() {
      return angular.equals($scope.newAdvert, $scope.emptyAdvert);
    };

    $scope.reset();    
  }
]);
```

[Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjEixF?p=preview)